# How to prevent S3-hosted website from being peeped

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to host a static website by AWS S3 (written in HTML and Javascript).

Then I am concerned that everyone can see the source code(ex:developer tools in chrome), in which I will write S3 information as well as credentials (like Identity Pool Id) because I will have access to S3 bucket.

I dont want to show up these information.
Then, are there any ways to hide the source code so that no one can see it?

Comment: No. there isn't a direct way to hide your source code.  Generally speaking, you can put poolid's in the code without much fear provided you have configured your access policies correctly. 

If you however you use a proxy (e.g. as described in https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/aws-mobile-app-backend-with-hybrid-apps/)

Then you can hide the S3

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand that, I do not have to be too nervous to reveal my pool IDs and what is important is to set appropriate policies. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript Obfuscator (https://obfuscator.io/) or similar tool to make Javascript source code unreadable (is not answer to your question, but helps protecting your intellectual property by  preventing people to  steal your code). Revealing account ID, user pool ID etc. is not a big issue. However, you should never include passwords etc. in the source code because obfuscation is not encrypting and text strings are not obfuscated. If you want that people are not able to see directly the different id values, you can include them in the code as base64 binary strings and decode them on runtime. This is not, however, encryption technique.